# Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace

Tags: git, tfs, sonarqube

I use SonarQube 6.2 with SonarQube.Runner 2.2.0.24. I would like to analyze a project on TFS Git. However, I get the error messages:

> [error]ERROR: Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace:
>   C:/Agent/_work/13/s/source/Services/Common/AddNewPerson_CommonApplicationService.cs
>   Missing blame information for the following files: ...[list of files]

I call the SonarQube Scanner with this command line:

```
C:\Program Files\SonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:FrontDesk /n:FrontDesk /v:4.0.70 /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=c:\Temp\Frontdesk.coveragexml /d:sonar.scm.enabled=true /d:sonar.scm.provider=tfvc /d:sonar.tfvc.username=[tfsbuilduser] /d:sonar.tfvc.password.secured=[tfsbuildpassword]
```

to end the analysis, I have the command

```
"C:\Program Files\SonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end
```

The files reported missing are on the path indicated on the build server.

How do I need to configure this project to make it work for TFS Git?

Comment: Which tfs build are you using? XAML or vNext build? And what's your detail TFS version?

Comment: It is a vNext build on TFS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your command `/d:sonar.scm.enabled=true /d:sonar.scm.provider=tfvc`  seems you are using [SonarQube SCM TFVC plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-tfvc). This is used for **TFVC**  source control, however you are using GIT source control.

You should execute the following commands:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"

SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

More info please refer this tutorial: [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild)

---

If you are using **vNext** build, you could use the two **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild** tasks to analyze Visual Studio solutions. More detail steps please take a look at below links:

- [SonarSource have announced their own SonarQube Team Services / TFS
  integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/12/13/sonarsource-have-announced-their-own-sonarqube-team-services-tfs-integration/)
- [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) (TFS2015 update3 and later)
- [Analyze your project with SonarQube in TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/10/31/analyze-your-project-with-sonarqube-in-tfs-build-vnext/) (For earlier TFS version)